# global char[] variable, how to declare it in other files?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, global, extern

I defined a global variable `char buf[1024]` in one file, and what's the correct may to declare it in other files? `extern char buf[1024]`, `extern char buf[]`, or `extern char *buf`? I found `extern char buf[]` works and `extern char *buf` doesn't, but would like to know more explanations.

Comment: See a very detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/694576

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
extern char buf[];
```

but **NOT**

```
extern char *buf;
```

Because **arrays are not pointers**.

Reference: [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr1.html)

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, except sometimes. Such as: `void foo(char array[100]) { strcpy(array, "I'm really a pointer, even though my declaration looks like an array"); }`

Comment: Can't single dimensional arrays be referred to by pointers with same syntax?

Comment: @anishsane: yes, but that's because of how indexing is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic.  In fact, when you index an array what happens is that the array name 'decays' to a pointer and the indexing happens via pointer arithmetic.  However, arrays still aren't pointers (except for in many function parameter declarations), they just behave like pointers in many, many situations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1462103/12711

Answer (score 0):

extern char buf[] and extern char buf[1024] both are ok.

In some case, the array is implemented by pointer, such as transfering arguments between two functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making a variable as extern ,  you are indicating to the compiler that the symbol (address) of the variable would be found in another .o file - ( This is done during linking stage ) .

So while you are making a variable as extern , you just need to mention the name as it will give the information about address and size is not required

Answer (score 0):

This is the old problem of arrays and pointers being interchangeable. Arrays and pointers are not interchangeable: they just happen to be most of the time, because most of the time you use an array name in an expression, where it decays into a pointer.

This specific case of defining as char array in one file and declaring as char pointer in the other file is thoroughly explained in Expert C Programming - Deep C Secrets; see chapter 4.

The declaration of an array gives you an array, and the declaration of a pointer gives you a pointer. The difference is that an array is an address - the address of the first element - and it is not a modifiable l-value, i.e., it can't be assigned to. On the other hand, a pointer is a variable holding an address.

Usually, the context is enough to tell whether you mean the address of a variable or the contents of the variable in an assignment. The statement

`i = j;`

Is saying to store the contents of `j` in the address of `i`. In compilers jargon, `i` is said to be an l-value, and `j` an r-value. The compiler has to generate code that writes the contents of the memory address of `j` in the memory address of `i`.

Consider these declarations:

```
char a[1024];
char *a;
```

What happens when you write `a[i] = j;`?

For the former case, the compiler will just pick the address of `a`'s contents, which, in arrays, is the address of the first element; scale `i`, and sum it to the base address. Then it will write the contents of the address where `j` is stored into that address.

For the latter case, it is quite different: the compiler has to check the memory location where `a` is stored, load the contents of that memory location, use THAT as an address, and write the contents of `j` into that address.

If you declare a characters array like this in `file1.c`:

```
char a[] = "Hello";
```

And then define, in `file2`

```
extern char *a;
```

Then, executing `a[0] = 'x';` in `file2.c` will crash: since you told the compiler that `a` is a pointer, it will check the address where `a`'s value is stored. In reality, this address is holding the character code for `'H'`, but the compiler mistakenly interprets that as an address, and ends up generating code to write `'x'` into the address `'H'`, which, if you're lucky, will crash your program with a segmentation violation.

Thus, this is a case where declaration and definition must match: if you declared it as an array, define it as an array; if you declared it as a pointer, define it as a pointer. You have to declare `buf` as a characters array in other files. Either of these forms is legal and equivalent:

```
extern char buf[1024];
```

or

```
extern char buf[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignable global char variable. Make visible to all:

```
// shared_header.h
extern char current_mode[];
```

Define, instantiate and update:

```
// main.c
#include "shared_header.h"

char current_mode[160];

int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
    strcpy(current_mode, "MODE_CONFIGURE");
    int a = randomNumber(102);

    strcpy(current_mode, "MODE_EXECUTE");
    int b = do_foo(a);
    // other stuff

    strcpy(current_mode, "MODE_TEARDOWN");
    // close up shop
}
```

Read or update:

```
// foo.c
#include "shared_header.h"

int do_foo(int a)
{
    printf("Current mode is %s", current_mode);

    if (a > 100) {
        strcpy(current_mode, "MODE_EXECUTE_SPECIAL_CASE");
        printf("Switching to mode %s", current_mode);
    }

    // do useful things
}
```